# Regex exclude lines not containing words but some words

Tags: java, regex, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using jenkins editable email plugin where i need to use regex to filter logs

I have this regex

```
 regex="(.*)fatal:(.*)"
```

which basically matches line start with fatal: so that i can grab errors

Example line look like this

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 1, "changed": true, "cmd": "nslookup test1.local",
```

But i want to grab all fatal erros except which conatin few worda like nslookup.

I want to ignore the above line which has nslookup and all other should be ok

Comment: Try this (.*)fatal:(?!nslookup).*$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a negative look ahead with a regex. This would work for your example:

```
^(.*)fatal: ((?!nsookup).)*$
```

To check for two different lookahead words:

```
^(.*)fatal: ((?!nslookup)(?!stuff).)*$
```

The (.*) at the beginning is only required if there can be something (whitespace or other characters) before "fatal:"

You can play with the expression with this link: https://regex101.com/r/ezxA5s/1